# No ManipulationCompleted event in Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch Beta

Tags: wpf, touch, pixelsense, multi-touch

I am using Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch Beta. I have a `UserControl` within a `ScatterViewItem` on a `ScatterView`. I want to receive `ManipulationCompleted` event on a `UserControl` but it doesn't seem to ever be raised even though `IsManipulationEnabled="True"` is also set. The same thing works perfectly in a non-Surface WPF4 app.

It appears various `Touch` WPF events play well with Surface but it seems like a lot of work to recreate a tap event and NSWE events that I can easily interpret from `ManipulationCompleted` event.

I am looking on ways to either receive `ManipulationCompleted` event on my `UserControl` or to simulate it by handling existing touch events.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

does the scatterviewitem move when your usercontrol is touched?  only one element at a time can be tracking manipulations for a given touch.  if the scatterviewitem is getting the manipulation events, that means your user control will not.

if you only want your usercontrol to handle the input, then have it listen to TouchDown and call usercontrol.Capture(touch).  if you want to have the SVI do it's thing but also handled the completed event on your own, then you will have to register your event handler manually: usercontrol.AddHandler( ManipulationCompletedEvent, yourHandler, true).  the last parameter says you want to handle the event even if SVI already has.